# Qt: How to handle a crash originated from inside a Qt class?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qtcore, qlist

I'm doing some research about handling errors in Qt-based application and after doing some reading about Qt usage of asserts instead of exception throw I came to the following question:

Some methods of Qt classes makes the application immediately crash when an error occur in them. For example, if I'm using a Qt container such as QList and calls for a member bigger then the container's size, the software is closed immediately:

```
QList<int> myList;
int itemp = myList.at(1);

//Crash!
```

Now I don't want that to happen in my application: if such an event occur, I want to handle that event (even if it is just to log something in a error log and close the app later). But how can I do that if Qt crash the software before I can do any error checking? And putting the code inside a try-catch wouldn't work since Qt throws nothing when this happens (at least not when exceptions are not enabled, which is what I pretend to use). Is there a way to go around this problem?

Comment: `if (myList.size() < 2) { /* present the error to the user in a helpful way, and don't crash. */ } else { ... = myList.at(1); }`, or design your application in such a way that the out-of-bounds request is never being made in the first place. Qt's assertion fails because it is reminding you that you messed up by getting yourself into that situation in the first place. You should fix the error instead of hacking in debug assertion catches. It is up to you, not to Qt, to not access past the end of a `QList`.

Comment: @JasonC thanks for the reply. Actually I agree with you partially (about why the assert and doing checkings before etc.). But the problem is that this is too much theory; in practice, a part of the code will be taken as "error-checked" and in real life will cause an error and for such situations I need an app that works around it pretty well, logging the error for further corrections and allowing the user to continue using the software without significant problems; there should be no place for crashes.

Comment: "In real life" a solid design and testing is even more important. Proper unit testing will help you identify and eliminate these potential crashes. *Proper* error handling will allow you to recover in the correct way. The crash you see should not be handled, it should be prevented. You don't access an index out of bounds then attempt to recover from the resulting seg fault. You check the bounds and report an error first. Both in theory and *especially* in reality. This isn't theory. Qt crashes there because it has an assertion failure *that is only designed to help debug* (or it seg faults).

Comment: @JasonC Well, I guess I got your point - not forgetting that the code I posted was only an example of "crashes arriving from inside a Qt class" (something that could happen even due to bugs inside the Qt library itself, not necessarily a result of bad coding from a Qt developer, and for this your solution seems useless while mine would do just fine :) ) Thanks!

Comment: @Momergil Your solution would not do just fine; worst case it leaves your program in a completely nondeterminate state. If QList's assertion doesn't catch the out of bounds access, you have no way of knowing what memory you might have blown away. This is a nightmare to debug. You can't control bugs in Qt itself, but by using it you do assume at least some amount of confidence that any issues in it would be quickly addressed, as the effect would be widespread and noticeable, at least if there were a bug in something as blatant as a container implementation. But your tests will uncover this.

Comment: @FinalContest \o/ I'm not accusing anything here! xD And while I do agree that the possibility of a bug inside Qt should not be taken in consideration while developing apps with it (I don't do that, btw), it still is the kind of condition that perfectly represents my idea of getting around an eventual bug that would arise from within a Qt class usage :)

Comment: All you need is to implement [crashrpt](https://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/). When you hit such assertions in your code, there is really no way for your application to continue. You need a separate process to take over, figure out where it crashed, and log and/or submit the crash report to you.

Comment: @KubaOber: you do not need crashrpt at least on *nix since you can just implement a fairly trivial one-liner signal handler and simple few-liner wrapper function.

Comment: @FinalContest Well you don't *need* it but crashrpt is much more than that; it's a nice little system for transmitting crash statistics and details back to home base for automated reporting, so the user doesn't have to deal with the report. It's actually quite nice - but crashrpt vs no crashrpt is orthogonal to the real issues here of course, which your answer covers nicely.

Comment: @FinalContest sorry for my ignorance, but I still haven't heard about how exactly to implement your solution (the "one-liner signal handler and simple few-liner wrapper function" or what you sad somewhere else. And Kuba, thanks for mentioning the crashrpt! Although the precise usage now is in embedded systems, so I'm not actually capable of using it :x

Comment: @Momergil: I put that into my answer, too... but you are supposed to do something on your own, too!

Answer (score 5):

This is not an actual crash. This is called SIGABRT on Linux, et al. What you are seeing is basically the result of Q_ASSERT_X:

```
template <typename T>
inline const T &QList<T>::at(int i) const
{ Q_ASSERT_X(i >= 0 && i < p.size(), "QList<T>::at", "index out of range");
 return reinterpret_cast<Node *>(p.at(i))->t(); }
```

This is not in any way Qt specific, just generic C++, so the only way to handle it is inherently platform specific. On Linux with POSIX for instance, you would write a signal handler that you register for that signal. Your could look up `man signal(7)` for instance. See this quote:

> Handling SIGABRT
>
> When handling this signal you should keep in mind how the abort(3) function works: it rises the signal twice, but the second time the SIGABRT handler is restored to the default state, so the program terminates even if you have a handler defined. So you actually have a chance to do something in case of abort(3) before the program termination. It's possible to not terminate the program by not exiting from the signal handler and using longjmp(3) instead as described earlier.

So, this is what you could basically do:

```
jmp_buf env;

void sigabrt_handler(int signum)
{
  longjmp (env, 1);
}

void handle_func(void (*func)(void))
{
  if (setjmp (env) == 0) {
      signal(SIGABRT, &sigabrt_handler);
      (*func)();
  }
  else {
      qDebug() << "Aborted\n";
  }
}
```

and then you would call this handler with your function:

```
handle_func(my_func_void_retval_void_args);
```

Similarly, you would need to implement this on all the platforms that you intend to use.

You could also just as well ignore it satisfying the macro condition in here, that is `QT_NO_DEBUG` defined and `QT_FORCE_ASSERT` undefined. The latter should be the default.

```
#if !defined(Q_ASSERT_X)
#  if defined(QT_NO_DEBUG) && !defined(QT_FORCE_ASSERTS)
#    define Q_ASSERT_X(cond, where, what) qt_noop()
#  else
#    define Q_ASSERT_X(cond, where, what) ((!(cond)) ? qt_assert_x(where, what,__FILE__,__LINE__) : qt_noop())
#  endif
#endif
```

See its documentation for details:

> Q_ASSERT_X is useful for testing pre- and post-conditions during development. It does nothing if \c QT_NO_DEBUG was defined during compilation.

Yet another way would be to check against [the size()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html#size) prior the actual indexing. That would spare you the crash. Let me give you an example:

```
QList<int> myList;
int itemp = myList.size() ? myList.at(1) : 0;
```

That being said, the idea of logging this error is questionable. You should avoid getting this error and not to handle it in hindsight.

Comment: +1 "You should avoid getting this error and not to handle it in hindsight." Qt in general shines with well-designed programs with proper preconditions and invariants, it would be best to find another way.

Comment: @FinalContest thanks for the reply. Although I agree with all the explanation above, it actually doesn't solve my problem :) Notice that it's not a matter of asserts (which I mentioned only because they are there...), it's a matter of CRASH. Even if I take the assert out by using QT_NO_DEBUG and QT_FORCE_ASSERT I'ld still have a crash on that line (or at least a bug...) that I need to handle appropriately. Again, saying "you should avoid getting this error" is too much theory; in practice bugs will appear no matter what and I need my software to know how to handle them correctly.

Comment: @Momergil: and what is wrong with the answer? Have you even checked the size part which I previously wrote in a comment? I still have no idea what kind of crash you are talking about though.

Comment: @FinalContest Ok, so you're saying that if I don't put conditional-checking before any possible place in my application where a crash may occur from inside a Qt class, then everything I'ld get is an application that can crash without having the opportunity to even write something in a error log what and where it happened? \o/ That doesn't seems fine for me :( Not to mention that I don't consider my idea a "hack", but only a "safety against undesired behaviour from currently unknown bugs around the usage of Qt classes" :)

Comment: @Momergil: and why is it difficult to write a macro or inline function for logging, checking, and indexing that would be called instead of at()?  Moreover, even the size() stuff is a hack, a user should never be able in any means to input incorrect values. That should be caught during the development which is the main purpose of an assert in C++ really is, basically.

Comment: @Momergil You don't have to e.g. write explicit code to check bounds on every access (although it would be trivially implemented with common strategies e.g. implementing a `QList`-based container that does bounds checking on access), but you at least have to check indices at points where they are specified "from the outside"; internally to a class (or whatever) you design so that you know if the public interface was passed a valid value, then all internal assumptions are also valid (and you can self-document this with asserts). C++ gives you all of these tools.

Comment: @FinalContest Exactly. Or, say, a `BoundsCheckedQList`. Or proper invariants with assertions to document and checks on publicly exposed interfaces.

Comment: What do you do if myList.size() fails. Because I have a medium size projects with a lot of threads. Calling size() fails, although myList is exists. !?